# Calling Python function with arbitrary number (not known at compilation time) of parameters from C++

Tags: python, c++

I need to make a call from C++ to a Python function of the form

```
def function(a, b, *c)
    print(a) # Mock example
    print(b) # Mock example
    print(c) # Mock example
```

**Requirement:** I shouldn't modify the Python function. They are provided by users and should have that signature for consistency.

The `Python.h` interface [provides](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/object.html) (quoting from the link to not make you have to open another page):

1. `PyObject* PyObject_CallFunction(PyObject *callable, const char *format, ...)`
   Return value: New reference.
   Call a callable Python object callable, with a variable number of C arguments. The C arguments are described using a Py_BuildValue() style format string. The format can be NULL, indicating that no arguments are provided.
   Return the result of the call on success, or raise an exception and return NULL on failure.
   This is the equivalent of the Python expression: callable(*args).
   Note that if you only pass PyObject * args, PyObject_CallFunctionObjArgs() is a faster alternative.
2. `PyObject* PyObject_CallFunctionObjArgs(PyObject *callable, ..., NULL)`
   Return value: New reference.
   Call a callable Python object callable, with a variable number of PyObject* arguments. The arguments are provided as a variable number of parameters followed by NULL.
   Return the result of the call on success, or raise an exception and return NULL on failure.
   This is the equivalent of the Python expression: callable(arg1, arg2, ...)

The number of arguments passed as part of `c` is not known at compilation time. At run time I have them as a `PyObject *` (let's call it `cc`) that points to a tuple. Let's say that the input for `a` I have it as a `PyObject *` called `ca`, likewise `cb` for `b` and that a `PyObject *` called `cfunction` holds the reference to `function`.

How can I make this call?

I have tried:

1. `PyObject_CallFunctionObjArgs(cfunction, ca, cb, cc)` and similarly with the other method passing the `format` string. But this seems to cause what in Python would be a call of the form `function(a, b, (c,))`. Inside the Python code the `c`, instead of being a tuple of the values that I had in `cc` is a 1-element tuple with first entry being the tuple of elements that I had in `cc`.
2. I also tried creating a new `PyObject *` `cd`, specifically a `PyTupleObject` containing as first two elements the content of `ca` and `cb` and the remaining elements being the elements of `cc`. Then I made a call like `PyObject_CallFunctionObjArgs(cfunction, cd)`. But this time Python complains that `function` requires the positional argument `b`. I assume because the tuple in `cd` is being given entirely to `a`.

Comment: `PyObject_CallFunctionObjArgs` needs a `nullptr` sentinel—you were lucky to get something so tame as an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following worked:

```
PyObject_CallFunctionObjArgs(cfunction, ca, cb, cc, NULL)
```

It produced the equivalent of a call in Python to

```
function(a,b,*c)
```

Answer (score 0):

You’re almost there: pass your `cd` tuple to `PyObject_CallObject` instead.

Comment: When I read the documentation I was sure that this was exactly what I needed, but something strange happened. For example, I called it with a tuple that contained `(1,2,3,4,5)` but it resulted in the call `function(1,2,3)`. I double checked the `PyTupleObject` and it does contain `(1,2,3,4,5)`. Will keep checking to see if it is due to some other error on my part.

Comment: @embeddedPy: …And you didn’t just accidentally check only the first element of the `c` tuple on the Python side?

Comment: Well, the following worked: `PyObject_CallFunctionObjArgs(cfunction, ca, cb, cc, NULL)`. I have no idea why `PyObject_CallObject(cfunction, cd)` didn't. Thank you for your help.